# Select Text After Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to select all text in-between following a specific pattern:

Sample Text:

```
"by thatonekid (Posted Mon Jan 12, 2009 7:17 pm)
fell onto the trail right below one of the most traveled walls at the point! yikes!

"
```

Every text I work on will start with: "by USERNAME (Posted DATE) `<br />` theTextIWant"

I thought about exploding on the paren's, but obviously, that could break up the text if there's another paren.

Secondly, some of the texts end in "`<br /><br />`".  I need to remove the trailing `<br />`'s if there is no text afterwards.

I apologize if this looks like I'm asking for someone to do my homework -- I honestly have no idea where to begin here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the text after the username/date, you can simply remove everything before the first <br />, assuming your formatting is consistent.

```
$text = preg_replace("/^.*?<br(\s\/)?>/si", "", $string);
```

This would replace everything before and including the first <br> or <br />, case-insensitive, with an empty string, leaving you with just the text.  The .*? at the beginning is a non-greedy match, meaning it will capture as little as possible.  In other words, it won't grab past the first break.

You can then follow this with:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^.*?<br(?:\s\/)?>(.*?)(<br(\s\/)?>)+$/si", "$1", $string);
```

This should remove all ending whitespace and <br>/<br /> tags.

You could also do all of this with a single preg_replace:

```
$text = preg_replace("/.*?<br(?:\s\/)?>(.*)(?:<br(?:\s\/)?>\s*)+$/si", "$1", $string);
```

I made all of the () captures (?:) non-captures, except the one containing the text.

(I don't use php regularly, so I am assuming that a perl compatible regex is what it says it is).

Comment: Thanks Jeff!

The first replace returns an empty string.  Any ideas?

The third one returns the following error:
Message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? or (?- at offset 8

Comment: What about adding a capture after the first BR, then simply returning the capture?  Any idea how that would work?

Comment: @jmccartie: OK, I fixed the problems in the first two.  I failed to use a 's' modifier to tell it to match on the entire string, including multiple lines.  Also, I added the ^ beginning of line match.  As for the third one, the correct non-capturing syntax is (?:) not (?), so I fixed that, but for some reason it still isn't working for me.

Comment: @jmccartie: I figured out the third as well.  Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you could try thoses regexp, with preg_match I guess. see online doc.

```
username : [_a-zA-Z09]+
date: [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}
```

(sorry gtg, helping you more later if unsolved)